# Executed shellcode terminates main program

Tags: c, assembly, execute, terminate, shellcode

I am trying to execute shellcode in a memory region. While it works so far, I am confronted with another problem right now: The main-c-program exits after I called the shellcode-program. Is there a (simple) way around this other than working with threads?

I think that this has something to do with the `mov rax, 60` and the following `syscall`, exiting the program. Right?

**Main-C-Code**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

const char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x1e\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x01\x00\x00\x00\x5e\xba\x0d\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05\xb8\x3c\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21";

// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Allocate some read-write memory
  void *mem = mmap(0, sizeof(shellcode), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  // Copy the shellcode into the new memory
  memcpy(mem, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

  // Make the memory read-execute
  mprotect(mem, sizeof(shellcode), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC);

  // Call the shellcode
  void (*func)();
  func = (void (*)())mem;
  (void)(*func)();

  // This text will never appear
  printf("This text never appears");

  // Now, if we managed to return here, it would be prudent to clean up the memory:
  // (I think that this line of code is also never reached)
  munmap(mem, sizeof(shellcode));

  return 0;
}
```

**Basis of the Shellcode** (assembler (Intel))

```
global _start

_start:
    jmp message

code:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    pop     rsi
    mov     rdx, 13
    syscall

    mov    rax, 60
    mov    rdi, 0
    syscall

message:
    call code
    db "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found it out by myself. If anyone is interested, the **simple solution** was to alter the assembler-code as follows:

```
global _start

_start:
    jmp message

code:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    pop     rsi
    mov     rdx, 13
    syscall

    ret        # Instead of "mov.., mov..., syscall"

message:
    call code
    db "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: The jmp-call-pop code should work without the "ret" instruction.  At least it works for me using a simpler C program.  Also, that "ret" instruction may ultimately have unintended consequences since it's popping the address (or whatever exists) off the top of the stack. So as your C code executes this section of code, without setting up a stack frame within the Assembly code, your next instruction may crash the program; thereby defeating the intent to the shellcode.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic I transferred the whole thing to ARM assembler code (since that was what I actually needed), this doesn't work. Skipping the "ret" (or in ARM the "bx lr") causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: You mean you ported the x86-64 code to ARMv7 code - right?  Does your ARM code execute properly in your main C program?

Comment: @InfinitelyManic We ported the ARM code, but the code itself works. We use the following:
`mov r0, #1`
`mov r1, string`
`mov r2, #12`
`mov r7, #1`
`swi 0`
`mov r7, #1`
`swi 0`

`string:`
`.ascii "Hello, World"`

We converted this to shellcode but this still exists our main C program. Leaving out the last syscall or replacing it with a `bx lr` leads to a segfault. Any ideas?

Comment: Just fixed it, when I execute this code inside of another program we need something different then `mv r7, #0` and `swi 0`. Instead I added `push {r0-r7, lr}` at the beginning and `pop {r0-r7, pc}` and `bx lr` at the end instead of the syscall. This works when it's being executed within another program as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

imo the simplest way would be to make a binary file, then exec() that. and if you need output from that then setup pipes.

Comment: I want to execute the code from a memory segment, this is easier with shellcode right? Any other ideas?